# PHP foreach array

Tags: php, arrays

I had to make some changes to my app to work with a relationship change in my db.

Originally I had whats below for a 1::0-1 relationship

```
if ($model->address->AddressLine1) echo $model->address->AddressLine1.'<br />';
if ($model->address->AddressLine2) echo $model->address->AddressLine2.'<br />';
if ($model->address->city->Name) echo $model->address->city->Name;
if ($model->address->city->regionCode->RegionCode) echo ', '.$model->address->city->regionCode->RegionCode;
```

but had to change it to work with a 1::0-n relationship

```
foreach ($model->address as $al1)
foreach ($model->address as $al2)
foreach ($model->address as $al2)
foreach ($model->address as $city)
foreach ($model->address as $region) {
    echo $al1->AddressLine1.' '.$al2->AddressLine2.'<br/>'.$city->city->Name.' '.$city->city->regionCode->RegionCode;
}
```

I want to retain the functionality of the `if` in my original code. With the original code I was able to use

`', '.`

in

`if ($model->address->city->regionCode->RegionCode) echo 
   ', '. $model->address->city->regionCode->RegionCode;`

to only add a comma after City only when a Region is present in the db.

So how can I get that back and utilize `if` within my array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need one `foreach` loop — you're just iterating through a single array.

You can stick the conditionals into the `foreach` loop, updating the variable name. This assumes that `$model->address` is an array. On each iteration `$address` will be set to a subsequent element of that array.

```
foreach ( $model->address as $address ) {
    if ($address->AddressLine1) echo $address->AddressLine1.'<br />';
    if ($address->AddressLine2) echo $address->AddressLine2.'<br />';
    if ($address->city->Name) echo $address->city->Name;
    if ($address->city->regionCode->RegionCode) echo ', '.$address->city->regionCode->RegionCode;
}
```

For more information:

- [PHP `foreach` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)
- [`foreach` tutorial](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/foreach.php)

Comment: this looks like what I am after.  This works with one address per item so I will add the multiple addresses per item and see if it completely fits the bill.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Works as expected.  Thanks again for the help.